# PHP: Refresh my code

Tags: php, mysql, refresh

Hello i want to refresh my php every 3 sec this is what i have:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../config.php";

$time = time();

$sql1 = "UPDATE login SET lastlogin = '" .$time. "' WHERE id = '" .$_SESSION['userid']. "'"; 
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

$onlinetime = "10";  // 10 seconds

$sql3 =  "SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY lastlogin DESC"; 
$res3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($res3)){

if($row3['lastlogin'] + $onlinetime > time()){

echo '<b><font color="green">&#10004;</font></b> <u>'.$row3['name'].'</u><br />';

        }else{

echo "<b><font color='red'>X</font></b> <u>".$row3['name']."</u><br />";
        }
        }            

?>
```

This is not refreshing which is really irritating. It shows who's online at my chatbox. Someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest using the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />` tag in the `<head>` section. **This does not depend on JavaScript**, and every major browser has this feature implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you're trying to do. The code has no mention of a refresh in it.

You could put the following in the  element of your HTML to force the client to refresh every three seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
```

Ian

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use ajax and poll a php script which checks for online users every X seconds.

I highly recommend jQuery for the ajax-part.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing a browsers content is something the browser should do. Either use the [`Redirect-After` HTML meta-tag](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/html-redirect/) (which will result in "flickering"), or use some Javascript to reload the site's content (see [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp))

Answer (score 1):

You could refresh using PHP header or something by that means. It works for me every time.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.com/'; $timeout = 5; //Directed URL and timeout.
header('Refresh: ' . $timeout . ';url=' . $url);
?>
```

Comment: aI do not know for sure, but it seems to work fine... Thanks.

Comment: it does not work, it is not refreshing. i did not change anything about this except the url.

Comment: @YourComputerHelpZ Did you place this above everything else? Also, you must change the 5 to your directed time, as you said (3?) seconds...

Answer (score 0):

You may adding some parens around `lastlogin + onlinetime`:

```
if($row3['lastlogin'] + $onlinetime > time()){
```

change to

```
if(($row3['lastlogin'] + $onlinetime) > time()){
```

Comment: What does this have to do with refreshing the page?

Comment: @seb; @joey;  you right only answer on my question please. This stuff i could do with the validator...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript reload:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="360; /">
```